# Null check operator error in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable

I am developing a Flutter app that implements OpenID authentication. I am getting the following error in one of the flutter libraries I am using (library https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client). The error is as follows:

```
E/flutter (14084): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled ExceptionNull check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (14084): #0      new Flow._
package:solidauth/…/src/openid.dart:344
E/flutter (14084): #1      new Flow.authorizationCode
package:solidauth/…/src/openid.dart:361
E/flutter (14084): #2      new Authenticator
package:solidauth/openid/openid_client_io.dart:23
E/flutter (14084): #3      AppLogin.authenticate1
package:solidauth/main.dart:873
E/flutter (14084): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14084): #4      AppLogin.build.<anonymous closure>
package:solidauth/main.dart:574
E/flutter (14084): <asynchronous suspension>
```

The piece of code that I am getting the error is the following:

```
class Authenticator {
  final Flow flow;
  final Function(String url) urlLancher;
  final int port;

  Authenticator(Client? client,
      {this.port = 3000,
      this.urlLancher = _runBrowser,
      Iterable<String> scopes = const [],
      Uri? redirectUri})
      : flow = redirectUri == null
            ? Flow.authorizationCodeWithPKCE(client)
            : Flow.authorizationCode(client)
          ..scopes.addAll(scopes)
          ..redirectUri = redirectUri ?? Uri.parse('http://localhost:$port/');

... some other functions ...
}
```

The error is coming from the above class constructor when I call it like the following. But I don't see any obvious errors in there. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
// create an authenticator
var authenticator = new Authenticator(client,
  scopes: scopes,
  port: 4000, 
  urlLancher: urlLauncher,
  redirectUri: Uri.parse(redirUrl));
```

Comment: Please debug which variable is null.

Comment: Check if ```client``` or ```redirUrl``` are nullable or not. Error might be thrown from one of those two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue comes from [this line](https://github.com/appsup-dart/openid_client/blob/0d65e6658324fb6dd34ee9dc7d4c440b4b614db6/lib/src/openid.dart#L341) in the class `Flow` because the `client` is null, so the null check `!` will throw that error.

```dart
  Flow._(this.type, this.responseType, this.client, {String? state})
      : state = state ?? _randomString(20) {
    var scopes = client!.issuer!.metadata.scopesSupported; <-- This line
    for (var s in const ['openid', 'profile', 'email']) {
      if (scopes!.contains(s)) {
        this.scopes.add(s);
        break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointing this out. Found that the error is coming from the line  `if (scopes!.contains(s))` because `scopes` is null.